Cache in vb.net
I am new at using cache.  I have the following code on an asp.net form codebehind in vb.net. This uses System.Runtime.Caching.
        Dim myTestValue As String
        Dim myRetrievedValue As String
        Dim myMessage As String
        Dim myCacheKey As String = "myTestKey"
        Dim myCache As ObjectCache = MemoryCache.Default
        '
        If myCache(myCacheKey) Is Nothing Then
            Dim policy As New CacheItemPolicy()
            policy.AbsoluteExpiration = DateTimeOffset.Now.AddMinutes(10)
            myTestValue = "ABCD"
            myCache.Set(myCacheKey, myTestValue, policy)
        End If
        '
        myRetrievedValue = myCache(myCacheKey)
        If myRetrievedValue Is Nothing Then
            myMessage = "Cache has failed."
        Else
            myMessage = "Cache has succeeded."
        End If

This works.  The value is added to the cache and the value is retrieved.  I call another page from the initial page.  This page codebehind is as follows:
        Dim myRetrievedValue As String
        Dim myMessage As String
        Dim myCacheKey As String = "myTestKey"
        Dim myCache As ObjectCache = MemoryCache.Default
        '
        myRetrievedValue = myCache(myCacheKey)
        If myRetrievedValue Is Nothing Then
            myMessage = "Cache has failed."
        Else
            myMessage = "Cache has succeeded."
        End If

Here no value is retrieved.  What am I doing wrong?

First, make sure Option Strict On is set for this project (and set it as the default for new projects). It will catch type mismatches for you, in case that is where the problem is.

Second, make the expiration a lot further into the future, e.g., DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddDays(1), in case there is some awkwardness with the time zone of the web server. Or just use a sliding expiration: .SlidingExpiration = TimeSpan.FromHours(1).

Third, make sure that the application pool for the website is not being recycled between pages, because that will destroy the cache. It would be unusual for that to happen, but you can set the recycling to happen at a specific time only, maybe in the early hours of the morning. (Look in the System event log in Event Viewer, if you do a manual recycle it'll add an entry from WAS with ID 5079 - it might be the same event ID for an automatic recycle.)

I made a minimal project to try and reproduce the problem in your question, but it worked as expected. Do you have any replies to my earlier comments?

Shout out to Andrew Morton for attempting to steer me in the right direction.

I could not get this working.  Maybe something to do with my unique development environment.  Based on my experience, I have now implemented a REDIS database for all my caching needs.  This seems to be working satisfactory.
